# Matlab syntax highlight: Avoid "reverse video" for "%%" at start of line

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim, matlab

I am using gVim 8.2 from Cygwin.  The synax highlighting recognizes code lines starting with "%%" at columns 1 and 2 show the text black characters on orange background.  It is not compatible with my color scheme, and my use of cursorline.  I wanted to disable this one part of syntax highlighting.

I tried to find the responsible file anyway to see if I could hack it.  I found `/usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/matlab.vim`.  I searched for the possibly responsible line by searching for `%%` and found:

```
syn match matlabCellComment     "^%%.*$"
   <...snip...>
hi def link matlabCellComment          Todo
```

I then browsed the `:syn-*` help pages and found that it is an entire language.  The following seems to turn off the "reverse video" without losing most of the synatx highlighting for Matlab:

```
" ~/.vim/syntax/matlab.vim
"-------------------------
hi! def link matlabCellComment NONE
```

However, any lines matching starting with `%%` at columns 1 and 2 now have no syntax highlighting.

**How can I get lines matching `^%%` to show up the same way that all comments do?**

I suspect that undoing the `syn match matlabCellComment "^%%.*$"` command might do the trick, but having perused the `syn-match` page, it's not clear to me how to do this.

Comment: Re: update—from a meta perspective, asking more than one question in a post is not how we do things (unless the case can be made for such tight coupling, which i font see here), and generally adding more questions after an answer is accepted is also not too good. You can always ask a new question. From a vim perspective, this is exactly the purpose of the after directory.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it seemed tightly coupled, since I was asking specifically about syntax highlighting rather than in the context of general commands like one might find in `vimrc`.  From your answer, however, I can see in retrospect that it is the same thing.  I've erased the update.  I appreciate the clarification on the `after` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
" ~/.vim/after/syntax/matlab.vim
highlight link matlabCellComment SpecialComment
```

You can also use plain `Comment`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Out of curiosity, however, do you know if there is a way to undo a `syn match` command?

Comment: @user2153235 outside of something nuclear like syntax clear? Not sure

Comment: Hmm, I don't want `syn clear` by itself, since that turns off all colouring. From the help, I tried `syn clear matlabCellComment`, but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: `:syn clear matlabCellComment` should work @user2153235

Comment: @Martin Tournoij: Thanks for checking!  I said that it didn't, but I neglected to say that I tried it in the `~/.vim/syntax/matlab.vim`. I updated my question with the details, but am still hoping there is a way to make it work in the user-specific `matlab.vim` file.

Comment: You can try adding an autocmd to `~/.vim/syntax/matlab.vim` @user2153235; not sure if that will work. But in general to override stuff from the system Vim you need to use either 1) `autocmd Filetype myfiletype [...]` or `~/.vim/after/[..]` like in this answer. The syntax files get loaded on every buffer, so that will override if you just stick it in your vimrc or `~/.vim/syntax/matlab.vim` (since the system Vim will be loaded *after* this file).

Comment: @Martin Tounoij: Thanks again.  Frankly, I didn't notice the `after` in the answer, and I stuck the `matlab.vim` into folder `~/.vim/syntax/`, which is why I was encountering my problem.